# Installing counterclockwise plugin manually

Tags: eclipse, clojure

I have given up configuring my proxy settings in eclipse to download plugins.  I want to install the counterclockwise plugins to run clojure in eclipse.  I can download the jars into my C:\Program Files\EclipseIDE 3.6\dropins.  Problem is when I start eclipse I dont have an option to start a new clojure project so I suppose the plugins are not being used.

The plugins I downlaoded are from http://ccw.cgrand.net/updatesite/plugins/.  Note I downloaded a single version only.

Answer (score 2):

You still use the Help -> Install New Software... option.  Move the jars into a directory that's not part of Eclipse.

On the Install dialog, left click on the Add... button, just as if you were installing software from a web site.

On the Add Repository dialog, to the right of the Location text box, is an Archive... button.  Left click that button and point to the non-Eclipse directory where your counterclockwise plug-ins are located.

Perform the rest of the install new software steps to install your jars.

Comment: Thx.  I tried that.  So in the Add Repo dialog, I click archive and navigate to my plugin dir and select the zip file (eclipseplugins.zip) that contains the clojure plugins and I get an error "could not find jar:file ...\eclipseplugins.zip!/  If I try selecting a particular jar file, I get the same error ie cannot find the ...jar file.  Any other suggestions gratefully accepted.

Comment: You need all of the update site to use the Install New Software, including the artifacts.jar and content.jar.  But how can you get the jars (or you just mean HTTP works fine, just eclipse won't)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.  http://ccw.cgrand.net/updatesite/ has a site.xml and all sub dirs.  I can't set my proxy in eclipse to get out of the company firewall so I am stuck.  Even though I can go to the site using a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the software manually on eclipse, find a zip file online.

Go to Help > Install New Software > Add > Archive and locate the zip file.

**IMPORTANT**

Make sure to untick the box "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" because if this is ticked it will give the "HTTP Proxy Authentication Required"

Answer (score -1):

Put the jars into the `/eclipse/plugins` directory.